# VBA to create two columns after last column, specific row with data

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a VBA that adds two named columns after the last column with data in row 16. I also want the named columns to be in row 16
I also want the VBA to go to Next workbook if rows "20th Percentile" and "80th Percentile" already exist

```
Sub create_columns_test2()
'insert two columns on every sheet in workbook after last column with data
    'named 20th and 80th Percentile

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    For Each WS In Worksheets

        If WS.Cells.Find("20th Percentile", "80th Percentile") = True Then Next
        x = Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        ' I want the code to use row 16 to check for last data
        .Cells(1, x + 1) = "20th Percentile"
        .Cells(1, x + 2) = "80th Percentile"
        ' I want these names in row 16


    Next WS


End Sub
```

I also get a "Compile Error" at `If WS.Cells.Find("20th Percentile", "80th Percentile") = True Then Next`

Comment: You cant put `Then Next` at the end of an `If` statement.

Comment: You can only use `Find()` to look for a single value - you can't pass in multiple string like that. And `x = Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count` should be `x = WS.UsedRange.Columns.Count`

Comment: Next workbook? Do you mean next Worksheet? Your code does nothing with parsing more than one workbook.

Comment: What do you suggest i do then if I can't put `Then Next` at the end of an `If` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. Hopefully the way it's written is explanation enough:

```
Sub create_columns_test2()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    For Each WS In Thisworkbook.Worksheets

        With WS

            If .Cells.Find("20th Percentile") Is Nothing And _
               .Cells.Find("80th Percentile") Is Nothing Then 

                x = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
                .cells(16,x+2).value = "20th Percentile"
                .cells(16,x+3).value = "80th Percentile"

            End If

        End With

    Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked. I just had to change 
`.cells(16,x+1).value = "20th Percentile"
 .cells(16,x+2).value = "80th Percentile"`
to
`.cells(16,x+2).value = "20th Percentile"
 .cells(16,x+3).value = "80th Percentile"`
otherwise it would go into the last column. not sure why

Comment: not sure why either @Zacchini - I just used the 1 and 2 based on your original code and the fact that you already obtained last column. Answer edited, but it would be good if you can clarify why the 1 and 2 do not work for future readers. You can debug the code step-by-step to see 1 and 2 do not put in the right column.